# How can we expand $(f(x)*d/dx)^n$? And why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, partial-derivative

Which one is the correct expansion of $(f(x)d/dx)^2$? $(f(x))^2  (d^2/dx^2)$ or $(f(x)d/dx)(f(x)d/dx)$? And why?

Comment: The power $n$ means that you apply the operator $n$ times. Thus, the second expression is the correct one. Note however that the $*$ in the middle of $(f(x)*d/dx)*(f(x)*d/dx)$ is not a product, but a composition of operators.

Comment: Dear Gary, Thanks for your reply. Here * is just a simple multiplication. I have a little doubt that since f(x) is just  a function, not an operator so can't we take it outside?

Comment: No you cannot, the "outter" $d/dx$ acts on the $f(x)$ in front of the "inner" $d/dx$. $f(x)d/dx$ is itself an operator.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: Did this question arise in the context of studying Quantum Mechanics? The trick to solve these type of questions is to make expression act on a scalar function. Finally , there will be some way to cancell the scalar function on both side of eqtn (see the first answer to the Q)

Comment: By the way, welcome to MSE! Generally speaking, I would suggest adding what exactly you googled/ books you checked before asking the question. It may have been difficult for you to find the answer to a particular question, but the user answering may have difficulty to understand that. Knowing the effort you've put in makes it easier to empathize , and also, for someone to write you an answer specific to the problem! Good luck!

Comment: This problem arise while studying A.A. Kilbas book page 99. There is a generalized derivative based on this formula which satisfy all the property for both kind of expansion for n and also some no on used it for n>1. They didn't mentioned about the expansion anywhere. So since I'm going to use it so I wanted to be sure. Thank you to all of you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $$\left(f\frac d{dx}\right)^2\phi=f\frac d{dx}\left(f(x)\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right).$$Apply the product rule to $\frac d{dx}\left(f(x)\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right)$ and then multiply by $f$.